# GRUB failure, install kernel first; can't mount partition in write mode

Tags: arch-linux, grub, boot-loader

GRUB failure, install kernel first; can't mount partition in write mode

After clean up on arch, grub is not loading:

> Loading Linux linux-zen
> error: file '/@/boot/valinux2-linux-zen' not found
> Loading initial ramdisk ...
> error: you need to instal kernel first

I booted live garuda installer.

Commonly proposed solution

> mount /dev/sda2 /mnt ; mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot

doesn't work as i can only mount sda1 as read only, can't arch-chroot there. I disabled windows safeboot and it didn't help.

I have some mess in partitions what might be the issue?:

> NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
> loop0          7:0    0  58.8M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/livefs
> loop1          7:1    0 437.3M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/mhwdfs
> loop2          7:2    0   1.1G  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/desktopfs
> loop3          7:3    0 699.8M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/rootfs
> sda            8:0    1  14.9G  0 disk
> ├─sda1         8:1    1   2.4G  0 part /run/miso/bootmnt
> └─sda2         8:2    1     4M  0 part
> zram0        253:0    0    15G  0 disk [SWAP]
> nvme0n1      259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk
> ├─nvme0n1p1  259:1    0   100M  0 part
> ├─nvme0n1p2  259:2    0    16M  0 part
> ├─nvme0n1p3  259:3    0   120G  0 part
> ├─nvme0n1p4  259:4    0     2G  0 part
> ├─nvme0n1p5  259:5    0   512M  0 part
> ├─nvme0n1p6  259:6    0    18G  0 part
> ├─nvme0n1p7  259:7    0     1G  0 part
> ├─nvme0n1p8  259:8    0  29.3G  0 part
> ├─nvme0n1p9  259:9    0  97.7G  0 part
> ├─nvme0n1p10 259:10   0   512M  0 part
> └─nvme0n1p11 259:11   0 207.9G  0 part

TBH I am a bit lost and prefer to ask you guys as probably it's elephant in the room I don't see.

Comment: At a guess I’d say sda1 and sda2 are partitions on a usb drive so you wouldn’t want to chroot there. One or more of the partitions on the nvme drive are probably your Linux installation. You probably need to mount the EFI partition and root partition correctly and chroot into it to fix things. Since you haven’t told us what you did when you “cleaned up” we cannot tell you what to do to fix things. However try installing a kernel and reinstall grub. Don’t forget to regenerate the main grub configuration file